# Totalizators for groups and sub_groups in a database? best practice

Tags: database, ms-access-2003

(this is a simplified version of the real problem)
I have a database that contains all the sales of the year.
Each row here contains: group, sub_group, sub_sub_group (yes! 3th levels), article_id, quantity;

The objective here is to make a report in ms-access 2003 where I get all the records in order of group, sub_group and sub_sub_group. But each time a sub_sub_group ends I need the sum of the quantity of all the articles contained by that sub_sub_group. The same must happen with sub_group and group.

What I've done is to create 3 views: a totalizers view for sub_sub_group, sub_group and group.
Then I join all that together, but that is not working as expected (of course!) because they are not in order.
(notice: in the article_id for the sub_sub_group I've wrote the string "sub_sub_total", and the same for sub_group and group)
(that worked when I only made the totalizers for the sub_sub_group but not for sub_group and group)

Any advice?
thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you can achieve this without a query, just by creating an Access Report. Reports are able to group data and build partial sums on each group during preparing the report.

Perhaps there is a wizard that may help you through this process.

Comment: but have only the total of what is shown. What I needed was the total of all items that ar of the family "a" for example, then "b" and so forth. And to place this info in a row at the end of the group.. I archived this by doing some dirty subqueries and hacking a little bit..

Comment: Ah right, I see that kind of report is not a "standard" one :-)

Comment: but is nothing of special neighter (: